# Trying to conditionally set navigation links based on redux state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I'm trying to conditionally set navigation links based on redux state that is initially undefined but being set asynchronously after an API call, however, the navigation links render once before the api response and is therefore always undefined. I'm looking for some advice in how to go about doing this successfully using react-native and redux.

the route configuration is -

```
export default createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Home: HomeStack,
    Search: SearchStack,
    ...!store.getState().UserReducer.user_id ? { Login: LoginStack } : { }
    }
);
```

The parent component is -

```
export default class App extends Component
{
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLoggedIn: false,
    }
  }

  componentWillMount()
  {
    fetch(ApiConfig.user.is_logged_in())
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(({data}) => {
      if (data.status === false)
        return;
      // Set user information.
      store.dispatch(setUserId(data.session.user_id));
      store.dispatch(setUserName(data.session.username));
      store.dispatch(setUserEmail(data.session.email));
      store.dispatch(setUserLastLogin(data.session.old_last_login));
      store.dispatch(setUserLastIp(data.session.last_ip));
      store.dispatch(setShowCost(data.session.show_cost));
      store.dispatch(setShowPrice(data.session.show_price));
      store.dispatch(setAvatar(data.session.avatar));
      this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true });
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }

  render()
  {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <NavigationStack loggedIn={this.state.isLoggedIn} />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What does the `ApiConfig` object look like in the parent component?